# Release 'release' is unavailable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am receiving an error that 'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference mode.

I have tried to google it but without luck.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] release];

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    statusImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"foto1" ofType:@"png"]];
    statusHighlightImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"foto1" ofType:@"png"]];

    [statusItem setImage:statusImage];
    [statusItem setAlternateImage:statusHighlightImage];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
    [statusItem setToolTip:@"Hejsa"];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using automatic reference counting (ARC), `release` statements are not necessary (the compiler handles memory management for you). You can just delete that call to `release` in the first line of `awakeFromNib`.